# Suppress jQuery error logging

Tags: jquery, ajax

In jQuery I use a ajax call to determine if a directory exists. If it gives a 403 error it has to do one thing if it gives 404 it has to use an other directory.

Everything is working as it should. Now the problem is whenever an error occurs jQuery logs the error to the firebug console. This shouldn't be happening.

Is there a way to suppress error logging in jQuery?

```
$.ajax({
url: "../media/",
complete: function(xhr, statusText) {
    if(xhr.status == 403) {
        //server is jetty
        mediaFolder = "../media/";
    }
}});
```

Comment: Are you sure it is jQuery doing the logs and not Firefox itself because of 404 errors?

Comment: I don't know, IE isn't showing the error but firefox is. So maybe it is a firefox problem but it still has to be suppressed. :P

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in way, a 404 is an error and its correctly displayed in the console (The error message well come directly from the XMLHTTP object rather than jQuery)

If you want to avoid it use a script to check on the server itself

```
url: "check_dir_and_return_parsable_result.blah?path=/xx/yy" ...
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes, cancel all `console.log()` lines in your code that are the likely cause of the logging

Comment: I don't use the console.log function, it's in the jquery code or something.

Comment: @baklap if you have no console.log() your code is not loggin anything explicitly, it's just firebug that displays the 404 or 403 as it would with any page